# what does setting cleanup to YES do in cocos2d removeChild?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I think I might be causing a bug in my code because I'm unclear about what the cleanup: part of removeChild:cleanup: method of cocos2d ccnode class.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It stops all actions and unschedules any scheduled selectors associated with the CCNode, basically removing any references that cocos could have to the object. It also propagates the cleanup invocation to all of the object's children. If the object is an autorealease-able object and you did not retain a reference to it, the memory should be reclaimed by the objective-c runtime, for the object itself and its children. That would be true of almost all objects, but not if you added the objected as a targeted touch delegate. In that case, I would recommend to override the onExit method as this:

```
- (void) onExit{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] removeDelegate:self];
    [super onExit];
}
```

this way, the object will be fully release-able when you cleanup.

Comment: i think the solution to my problem is to set NO for cleanup, I'm just not sure what drawbacks there are to that.

Comment: That would be quite unusual , setting to NO ... potential leaks lurk if you are not careful. I am guessing that you are keeping a reference in your code to the object, or one of its children ... 's children, and get an error similar to 'message sent to deallocated instance' somewhere along the line. It is best to find that reference and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

cleanup basically specifies whether the running actions for that particular node should be cleaned up or not, basically, if it's set to YES, the object that's being removed will stop all running actions and unschedule all selectors.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I think this makes sense but when you say all running actions what do you mean? the ones associated with the child?

Comment: The actions that are currently still running on the node. Frankly, there's very little reason not to set cleanup to YES. This may only be helpful if you, for some reason, want to remove a node from its parent only to add it to another node without interrupting the actions the node is running.